# JSON Schema construction for a objects with. common properties but differing in some properties

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a a number of objects which share a common set of features but differ in one or more properties.  The common content is specified as media content in the definitions. I have provided one such object with a 'format' property, but there are other objects, omitted to keep it short, that also have additional properties. Here is a snippet of my attempt at constructing the schema. Is this the correct way to accomplish, this? Many thanks

```
 "definitions": {
 "media-content":{
  "type": "object",
  "title": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "related-media": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
 },

 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
    "type": {
        "format": "string",
        "enum":["audio", "video"]
    },
    "category": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/media-content"
    }             
 }
```

Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that stands out to me is that this isn't valid JSON Schema.

The `title` keyword provides a title *for the schema* so it expects a string, but because you've provided a schema, it looks like you're wanting it to be a property.  Similarly `related-media` looks like you expect this to be a property.  Are you missing wrapping these in a `properties` keyword, like you have later for `type` and `category`?

These changes would make `media-content` look like this:

```json
"media-content":{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "related-media": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> I have provided one such object with a 'format' property

Again, here, I'm not sure what you're getting at.

```json
"properties": {
    "type": {
        "format": "string",
        "enum":["audio", "video"]
    },
    "category": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/media-content"
    }             
 }
```

This says you're expecting `type` to be a property in your object, but `format` isn't used right.  Although the `format` keyword has some predefined types and *does* accept custom values, the way you're using it look like you really want to be using the `type` keyword.  In the end, it doesn't matter because `enum` will restrict the value to the items you declare in the array (`"audio"` or `"video"`).

It might be easier to see what you're trying to do if you posted a full minimum exaple.

That said, I'll try to build one to answer the question I think you're asking.

---

It sounds like you're wanting to build a polymorphic relationship: an inheritance hierarchy where a base type defines some properties and a number of derived types define additional properties.

There's not really a good way to do that with JSON Schema because JSON Schema is a *constraints* system.  That is, you start with `{}` where anything is valid, and by adding keywords, you're reducing the number of values that are valid.

Still, you might be able to achieve something close by using `allOf` and `$ref`.

First, declare the base property set in its own schema.  I'd separate them into independent schemas for easier handling.  You also need to give it an `$id`.

```json
{
  "$id": "/base-type"
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "base-prop-1": { "type": "string" },
    "base-prop-2": { "type": "number" }
  }
}
```

Next, for each of your "derived" schemas, you'll want to create a new schema, each with their own `$id` value, that references the base schema and declares its own additional requirements.

```json
{
  "$id": "/derived-type-1",
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "/base-type" },
    {
      "properties": {
        "derived-prop": { "type": "boolean" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This second schema requires everything from the `/base-type` and also requires a `derived-prop` property that holds a boolean value.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to build, like  you. mentioned,  an inheritance hierarchy. I just did not express it like you did. Thank you very much.